# Bootstrap Validator - wrong max value validation for input type range

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have input field this

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="StarRate">Star Rate</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter star rate" type="range" name="StarRate" min="1" max="6" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)" value="">
            <output for="StarRate" id="rating"></output>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_id').bootstrapValidator();
});
function outputUpdate(vol) {
    document.querySelector('#rating').value = vol;
}
```

The problem is that when I select max value i.e. 6 then it shows error message `This value is not valid`. So whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I did a JSFiddle for you:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/m6xjp821/
```

Found some mistakes, one in the `<input .... value=""` could be one reason.

Second is I did a workaround for your outputUpdate function.

The Fiddle is working.

> New Html Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="StarRate">Star Rate</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input id="switcher" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter star rate" type="range" name="StarRate" min="1" max="6" step="1" value="1">
            <output for="StarRate" id="rating"></output>
        </div>
 </div>
```

> New JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#form_id').bootstrapValidator();
});

$("#switcher").on("input", function() {
    console.log("test");
    document.getElementById('rating').value = $("#switcher").val();
});
```

Comment: till its not working for max value returns same error. Is this related with bootstrapValidator version?

Comment: It's working in the Fiddle? If not then i don't understand your problem.

This are the libs in the fiddle:
[bootstrap.validator.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js)
[bootstrap.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js)
[jquery.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js)